# Cannot read client's X509 certificate in Spring Boot mTLS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, mtls

I want to read client's x509 certificate in a mTLS connection. I am using Spring Boot with embedded tomcat.

My `WebSecurityConfig.java`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .x509().withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<X509AuthenticationFilter>() {
                    @Override
                    public <O extends X509AuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O filter) {
//                        filter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(false);
                        return filter;
                    }
                }).and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout((logout) -> logout.permitAll());


        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("u")
                        .password("p")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

I have a `UserController.java`

```java
@Controller  
public class UserController {  
    @Autowired  
    private HttpServletRequest context;  
  
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")  
    public String user(HttpServletRequest request) {  
  
        X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");  
        System.out.println(certs[0]);  
  
        return "user";  
    }  
}
```

My `application.yml`

```yaml
server:  
  port: 8081  
  ssl:  
    enabled: true  
    key-store: "classpath:server.p12"  
    key-store-password: 123456  
    key-store-type: PKCS12  
    client-auth: need  
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2  
  
    trust-store: "classpath:server.p12"  
    trust-store-type: pkcs12  
    trust-store-password: 123456
```

Then I run the code using `mvn spring-boot:run -DclientAuth=true`

But it seems, certificate is null when I hit the `/user` endpoint.

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "certs" is null
    at com.example.securingweb.UserController.user(UserController.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:150) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My `keytool -list -keystore server.p12` output:

```
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

1, Jan 27, 2023, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 4F:04:0B:CF:21:AB:45:4A:17:C1:83:93:B0:5D:3C:D4:04:80:B2:0B:79:24:68:70:18:36:5C:CE:7B:77:6C:23
bcc, Jan 27, 2023, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): 49:EF:A6:0F:E7:81:71:22:2B:F5:BD:D0:76:48:77:70:EE:5E:E9:23:BB:FF:66:AC:68:2D:CB:D3:4F:D1:87:DC
torsho, Jan 27, 2023, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): C0:42:3A:FD:9F:00:A9:6D:05:8B:2F:F9:B9:DE:A7:A7:DA:6F:19:6B:D7:33:34:D6:4F:D3:D8:78:12:AA:25:0A
```

[My full project](https://github.com/desertSniper87/spring-boot-mtls)

Comment: What url do you use? Did you install the client-certificate into the browser?

Comment: Using chrome/chromium, did you activated `chrome://flags#allow-insecure-localhost`? Firefox, did you activated `about:config#security.default_personal_cert`?

Comment: Is the public part of the client-cert within the server's truststore?

Comment: Is the client-certificate issued by the server only? Is the client-certificate signed by the server's certificate?

Comment: @Grim, I create a root CA, client certificate and server certificate using openssl (https://torsho-digital-garden.netlify.app/net/sec/pki/tls/implementation-of-m-tls-in-node-js/). I then imported the root CA as a certificate authority and client certificate as my certificate in firefox. The client.crt is imported into the truststore using `keytool -import -alias torsho -file ~/dev/mTLS-nodejs-poc/client.crt -keystore server.p12 -storepass 123456`. The client certificate and server certificate both are signed by the root CA. Then. I am going to https://localhost:8081/user in firefox.

Comment: I can enter the website by choosing the certificate but cannot get the client certificate in the application layer in the spring boot application.

Comment: I am using `https://localhost:8081/user` to hit the webpage.

Comment: @desertSniper87 you can enter an authenticated URL (other than `/`, `/home` and `/login`)?

Comment: @dur, yes i can.

Comment: @desertSniper87 Your code looks correct. All things you told looks correct. Indeed, very interresting! +1 from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
jakarta.servlet.request.X509Certificate
```

instead of

```
javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate
```

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/servletapi/jakarta/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you. Dumb me did not remember I was using java 17

Comment: @desertSniper87 Your not dumb, I love to see that somebody does mutual-authentication!